# Existence of homotopy between polynomial maps?

Tags: general-topology, polynomials, homotopy-theory

Consider two non-constant polynomial maps $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $g: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Suppose the degree of $f$ does not equal the degree of $g$. Show that there does not exist a homotopy $h:[0,1] \times \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ from $f$ to $g$ such that $h$ is a proper map. (Recall that a continuous map is proper means that the preimage of any compact set is compact.)

We know that every polynomial on $\mathbb C$ is proper, but why does the straight line homotopy $h(t,z):=(1-t)f(z)+tg(z)$ doesn't work here? What about other kinds of homotopy? I don't fully understand this so I don't know how to proceed, or, what is the key proof to the problem?

Comment: Well, how do you know the straight line homotopy is proper?

Comment: Hmm I don't think it's proper, because the leading coefficient of z at a time t will be too small, but I don't know how to explain this in other kinds of homotopies···

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see, in your example $h$ isn't proper because the leading coefficient of $z$ at a time $t$ will be too small, and the module of the root can be arbitrary big, leading to unbounded sets which means $h$ isn't proper. Hence we only need to prove that the inverse of $0$ is unbounded.

Assume such homotopy exists, then there exists $r>0$ such that $h^{-1}(0)\subset [0,1]\times B_0(r)$, hence $h$ is a homotopy from $f$ to $g$ defined on $[0,1]\times (\mathbb C\backslash B_0(r))$ with its image being $\mathbb C\backslash\{0\}$. Since homotopy doesn't change degree of functions, and $\mathbb C\backslash B_0(r)\simeq \mathbb C\backslash\{0\}\simeq S^1$, we must have $deg(f)=deg(g)$, which is not true from our assumptions.